How to create a custom field in Symfony with EasyAdmin
I'm building a website using symfony 7 and EasyAdmin 4, I'm learning how to use this framework so I don't get how everything connect together yet.
The problem I'm having is with the library 'Trumbowig' and custom fields.
I made it work but it was just a test to see if all needed files where working, now I want to create a custom field to be able to use this feature properly.
I don't understand how to create the template that will be used in forms.
I've read the documentation here, looked at TextEditorField and TextAreaField in EasyAdmin package.
I found that I need a custom class for my field, so I made this TrumbowygEditorField class:
final class TrumbowygEditorField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public const OPTION_MAX_LENGTH = TextField::OPTION_MAX_LENGTH;
    public const OPTION_NUM_OF_ROWS = 'numOfRows';
    public const OPTION_RENDER_AS_HTML = TextField::OPTION_RENDER_AS_HTML;
    public const OPTION_STRIP_TAGS = TextField::OPTION_STRIP_TAGS;
    public const OPTION_TRUMBOWYG_CONFIG = 'trumbowygConfig';

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            // this template is used in 'index' and 'detail' pages
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/trumbowyg_editor.html.twig')

            // this is used in 'edit' and 'new' pages to edit the field contents
            ->setFormType(TextareaType::class)
            ->setCustomOption(self::OPTION_TRUMBOWYG_CONFIG, [])
            ->setCustomOption(self::OPTION_MAX_LENGTH, null)
            ->setCustomOption(self::OPTION_NUM_OF_ROWS, 5)
            ->setCustomOption(self::OPTION_RENDER_AS_HTML, false)
            ->setCustomOption(self::OPTION_STRIP_TAGS, false);
    }


And made the template for index and detail :
{% set render_as_html = field.customOptions.get('renderAsHtml') %}
{% if ea.crud.currentAction == 'detail' %}
    <span title="{{ field.value }}">
        {{ render_as_html ? field.formattedValue|raw|nl2br : field.formattedValue|nl2br }}
    </span>
{% else %}
    <span title="{{ field.value }}">
        {{ render_as_html ? field.formattedValue|raw : field.formattedValue|striptags }}
    </span>
{% endif %}

It seems to be working as expected at index page.
Now I'm having trouble to understand how to make the form field, I know that it's related to this line ->setFormType(TextareaType::class), and I need to find a way to import a css file, some js scripts and execute something like this :
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        $('{{ fieldId }}').trumbowyg();
    });
</script>

But I don't know how to proceed, do I need to build a custom formType ?
Can you help me please ? Thank you.

I've found a solution without creating a new field, I override the field template that I want to apply trumbowyg and also edit/new crud templates to inject css and js at their right location.
How I proceeded :
In "EntityNameCrudController" :
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
    return $crud
        ->addFormTheme('admin/project/_form_theme.html.twig')
        ->overrideTemplate('crud/edit', 'admin/project/edit.html.twig')
        ->overrideTemplate('crud/new', 'admin/project/new.html.twig')
        ;
}
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        TextEditorField::new('content'),// targeted field
    ];
}

In "admin/project/_form_theme.html.twig" :
{% block _Project_content_widget %}
{% set targetField = 'trumbowygContent' %}
<textarea id="{{ targetField }}" name="{{ field_name(form) }}" required="required" class="form-control">{{ field_value(form) }}</textarea>

{% endblock %}
And for "admin/project/edit.html.twig" and "admin/project/new.html.twig" I copy/paste from 'easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/views/crud/' the files with the same name and added theses lines :
{% block head_stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/trumbowyg/ui/trumbowyg.min.css') }}">
{% endblock %}{% block body_javascript %}
{{ parent() }}
{{ include('trumbowyg/import.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}

I can adapt it to other controller with few modifications, It's not as good as a custom field, but it's working.
If you have a better solution I would love to hear it.
